# postgresql error PANIC: could not locate a valid checkpoint record

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.0

When I load up the postgres server (v9.0.1) i get a panic that prevents it from starting:

> PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please don't post the solution in the question itself. Answering your own questions is not discouraged, but you should post solutions as answers. I've edited the solution out of the question this time. Feel free to post it as an answer at your convenience.

Comment: I'm actually curious what was the answer before Anna edited it out :-)

Comment: If this is on a slave / read server and you've started up after copying over the base backup, make sure that you have the label file that was created when creating the base backup in the local data folder.

Answer (score 185):

Postgres is looking for a checkpoint record in the transaction log that probably doesn't exist or is corrupted.

Before you proceed, **you must be aware that the below can make things worse** if you are unlucky. `pg_resetwal` could leave your database in an indeterminate state as explained in the [PostgreSQL documentation on `pg_resetwal`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgresetwal.html):

> If `pg_resetwal` complains that it cannot determine valid data for
> `pg_control`, you can force it to proceed anyway by specifying the
> `-f` (force) option. In this case plausible values will be substituted
> for the missing data. Most of the fields can be expected to match, but
> manual assistance might be needed for the next OID, next transaction
> ID and epoch, next multitransaction ID and offset, and WAL starting
> location fields. These fields can be set using the options discussed
> below. If you are not able to determine correct values for all these
> fields, `-f` can still be used, but the recovered database must be
> treated with even more suspicion than usual: an immediate dump and
> reload is imperative. Do not execute any data-modifying operations in
> the database before you dump, as any such action is likely to make the
> corruption worse.

You can determine if this is the case by running:

```sh
# Postgres >= 10
pg_resetwal DATADIR

# Postgres < 10
pg_resetxlog DATADIR
```

If the transaction log is corrupt, you'll see a message like:

```
The database server was not shut down cleanly.  
Resetting the transaction log might cause data to be lost.  
If you want to proceed anyway, use `-f` to force reset.
```

You can then follow the instructions and run with `-f` to force the update:

```sh
# Postgres >= 10
pg_resetwal -f DATADIR

# Postgres < 10
pg_resetxlog -f DATADIR
```

That should reset the transaction log. However, as stated above, this is a risky operation.  You might be better off seeking professional advice.

Comment: Resetting via `pg_resetwal /usr/local/var/postgres/` then running postgres like `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres` worked for me.

Comment: thanks. `pg_resetwal $PGDATA` for docker. just make to run `su postgres` before execution

Comment: If `pg_resetwal /var/lib/postgresql/data/` gets you an error `pg_resetwal: error: cannot be executed by "root"`, then you have to use the command `su postgres` to become the user `postgres` which is usally the owner of that folder. If you want to see who is the owner of the folder, use `ls -l /var/lib/postgresql/data/`.

Comment: This `pg_resetwal` is located in `/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin`

Answer (score 29):

****In case of docker,****

This error will result in the container getting constantly killed and restarted.
The first step is to get the container up and running so that we can exec into the container and run pg_resetwal or pg_resetxlog .
In the postgres [docker layer](https://hub.docker.com/layers/postgres/library/postgres/9.6.22-buster/images/sha256-9f9ba52874ec205baacc7434cfa20fcfbe3cbf99e31123e4737048472328a369?context=explore) info, we can see that

**ENTRYPOINT** is ["docker-entrypoint.sh"] and **CMD** is ["postgres"]

docker-entrypoint.sh script will run any linux command passed as argument.

If you are on docker then passing **/bin/bash** will override default CMD and give you access to container shell,

```
docker run -it -v /my_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:9.6.22 /bin/bash
```

here **/var/lib/postgresql/data** is the postgres data directory inside the container.

Once inside the continer, run below commands based on your postgres version. This will reset the transaction logs (WAL)

On postgres >= 10

```
pg_resetwal /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

On postgres < 10

```
pg_resetxlog /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Top rated answer on this thread explains more on the pg_resetwal commands.

Finally, you can exit this container and start the postgres DB container with its original CMD.

---

**Some Additional Info**

If you see below error, it might be because the data directory you have specified above might be incorrect.

**pg_resetxlog: could not open file "PG_VERSION" for reading: No such file or directory**

You can check the PGDATA env variable for the right path.

```
root@4650984c476b:/# printenv | grep PGDATA
PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

---

With older vesion of postgres below error might occur.

**pg_resetxlog: cannot be executed by "root"**

This can be [resolved by running below command](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/158).

```
gosu postgres pg_resetxlog /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

---

In case of any container orchestrator like **kubernetes**, rancher v1 (since we cant run docker commands directly), we will have to start the container with a process like sleep. Pass the below as cmd or args in your orchestrator [manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40093356/6563567).

```
sleep infinity
```

or

```
sh -c 'while sleep 3600; do :; done'
```

Then enter the container using tool like **kubectl exec**. Once you are inside, pg_resetwal/pg_resetxlog commands can be run.

Comment: Just as I side note, in case anyone does not immediately have the `bin` set up with PATH. I was able to fix the problem using the explicit command: `/usr/lib/postgresql/<VERSION>/bin/pg_resetwal /var/lib/postgresql/data`

Comment: And also adding `PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data` to `ENV` vars

Answer (score 27):

I'm running 9.1.7 and i find ran the following successfully:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_resetxlog -f /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main
```

Your final argument to the `pg_resetxlog` command should be the location on disk where postgres stores your database data.

Comment: The same works for 9.6 inside Docker container

Answer (score 15):

As [indicated here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/531307/postgres-xc-will-not-install-due-to-broken-packages#531316) pg_resetxlog should not be run.  The answers that refer to this is bad advice.  Assuming the error occured in a context of copy/replication instance, the link provides a more succinct way of doing copy/replication with `pg_basebackup`

Answer (score 4):

Do you do continuous archiving?  If you are backing up at the time, you may find it more prudent to remove backup_label.  `pg_resetxlog` is a severe thing.

Answer (score 4):

I came across here with a Docker Postgresql-13 which did not start again.
I fixed it by finding the volume (for the data) and running

Being in the volume data folder, e.g., `/var/lib/docker/volumes/c4c8d637d9eee086265d732b2974690b731abcb23f47ca61bf75fe28526e31ce/_data`

run as owner of the directory (for me it was the systemd-coredump user)

`sudo -u systemd-coredump /usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/pg_resetwal -f .`

For sure you need the same Postgresql version installed (if the `pg_resetwal` is not part of the volume)

worked

Comment: this works directly: `docker run --rm -it -u=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -v /pg_dbdata_dir:/some_dir postgres:13.4-buster /bin/bash -c "pg_resetwal -f /some_dir"`

Answer (score 3):

In case of Windows Server if you see Postgresql showing ERROR "could not locate a valid checkpoint record"
Dont worry just run below command on Power Shell :

Open the folder C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin  on power shell ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdFLh.png))  and then run :

```
.\pg_resetwal.exe -f -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data"
```

Complete command will be :

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin.\pg_resetwal.exe -f -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data";
```

After that when you see a message **"Write-ahead log reset"** then you can run postgresql service it will run 100 percent,also ensure all running task of postgresql should be end before start Potgresql service

Answer (score 1):

just like the log saying : could not locate a valid checkpoint record.Postgres can't find a properly WAL under the $PGDATA/pg_xlog/ directory.
Try to use  pg_resetxlog

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for Postgres 14. I was getting the same error in the standby logs after the following steps:

1. Login to stand-by.
2. Create back up with the below command:

> pg_basebackup -D $APP_BACKUP_PATH -F t -P -v -U replicator -w
> --no-password -h 10.29.51.98

3. Extract generated `$APP_BACKUP_PATH/base.tar` to standby data directory.
4. Restart the standby. The start up fails with :  `PANIC: could not locate a valid checkpoint record`.
5. So, it turns out that the backup was not generated right. It needs to be generated with an additional option `-X stream`.
6. After regenerating and applying the updated back up to the stand by data directory, the stand-by came up without this error.

Answer (score -1):

The same problem happened to me importing the data from another server. The problem was that the locale was different between the two servers.

My database was created with `en_US.UTF-8` but the locale was set to `C` on the server where the data was to be imported.

On Debian, running `dpkg-reconfigure locales` did the trick.