# The postgresql-x64-9.6 service on local computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use

Tags: postgresql

Postgresql service not starting in services.msc. it is showing below message while starting PostgreSQL service in Window server 2008 R2.

" The postgresql-x64-9.6 service on local computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs."

[image]

Comment: Check the PostgreSQL logs and your event viewer logs.

Comment: in event viewer log it is showing timed out error message.

Comment: @user3931984 - Please ask this question on ServerFault or SuperUser. This is not about a programming problem, so it doesn't belong on SO.

Comment: with details: exact error messages from event viewer and postgres logs. As text not screenshot so they're searchable.

Comment: event log : FATAL:  XX000: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin\postgres.exe: could not locate matching postgres executable
LOCATION:  getInstallationPaths, d:\pginstaller_13.auto\postgres.windows-x64\src\backend\postmaster\postmaster.c:1489   any idea?

Answer (score 24):

I had this same issue. and i followed @Craig Ringer's advice. when i check the event viewer i got this error.`2018-06-18 12:34:11.222 GMT [4200] FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
2018-06-18 12:34:11.222 GMT [4200] HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 6172) running in data directory "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/data"?` so i deleted the "postmaster.pid" file in my postgreSQL data directory, start the service again and this time around, the service started properly. 
This error might be due to incomplete shutdown of the postgreSQL service.

Comment: Event Viewer → Windows Logs → Application. My `Error` from `PostgreSQL` says `postgres: superuser_reserved_connections (3) plus max_wal_senders (10) must be less than max_connections (10)`. Seems I misconfigured the `max_connections`. Solved, thanks.

Comment: And delete `postmaster.opts` file in same directory as well. Then restart service. It should be fine with out any error. I hope it will be helpful. :)

Answer (score 22):

For some reasons postgresql process is still running in the background.

You can encounter this problem if your system forcefully shutdowns down.
Solution:

1. Windows + X (Open task Manager - Processes)
2. Find all running postgresql  services and 'End Task'.

After all processes have ended. You can reopen task manager to ensure no postgres services is running.

3. Restart Postgresql server

Comment: I had exactly the same problem described in the original post and this worked for me.

Comment: I had the same experience: "postgresql server 14 service on local computer started and then stopped" error, but I can open databases using pgAdmin 4. This solution solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I have an additional answer to the ones here as to why the somewhat misleading error message can occur, which is now a newer version, 12.2 vs 9.6, ("The postgresql-x64-12 - PostgreSQL 12 Server service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.)

Apparently, errors in the pg_hba.conf file will cause the error message above to appear, and the service failed to start.

In my case, I had edited the file and failed to comment out (#) a comment properly. After much Googling, I never saw that mentioned but DID finally remember to double-check my edits, and there the problem was a simple mistake.

I fixed it and the service now starts, no problem.

-Windows 10 x64 Enterprise 1909 18363.752
-PostgreSQL 12.2 (Windows)

Comment: Same thing happened to me. I edited pg_hba.conf and later tried to restart the server it wouldn't run anymore. Had to fix pg_hba.conf to make it work again. So +1.

Answer (score 7):

I've solved same issue.
Here I have done.
I deleted two files and then restart service. Please these files:`postmaster.opts`, `postmaster.pid` in "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/data" directory.
As you seen @Abodesegun Ezekiel's answer, I deleted one more file called "postmaster.opts"
and it worked for me.

Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was solved by changing the account that runs the service to "Local System" and after that, I was able to start the service.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this error was caused by editing shared_buffers and work_mem parameters in postgresql.conf file to too high values, lowering them solved the issue

Comment: Kudos...That was the issue in my case

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem. I have hard coded the path for the `hba_file` in the `postgresql.conf`. That works. For some reason there is a path name prefix from windows which causes to search in the wrong path for the `pg_hba.conf` file.  Now this works and I can start the service and open the database.

Comment: Similar issue, config error in postgresql.conf. I find the error message a bit misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Came across the same error with `Postgresql-9.4` in Windows-10.

In my case I have a few manual config updates made in `postgresql.conf` file, and had to validate the syntax of the configuration changes made in the `postgresql.conf` file. I've followed the below steps that fixed the issue.

- Delete the `postmaster.pid` file in `%POSTGRESQL-HOME%/9.4/Data/` directory
- Provide correct syntax (or references) in `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` files
- Restart the Postgresql service

Answer (score 1):

Check the error logs:

<postgresql_path>\data\log

In my case, it was a simple syntax error after adding a conf in pg_hba.conf

Answer (score 1):

For me, killing the process, deleting the pid file, restart, etc. did not help.
What worked was:

**1- Check the status:**
Change the directory to the installation folder and go inside the *bin*. The path is like:
`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin`
use the pg_ctl to get the status:
`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin>pg_ctl.exe -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data" status`
The path here is the *data* folder.
The result was:
`pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 7560)`
Even though the service was not running in the windows service page.

**2- Stop:**
`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin>pg_ctl.exe -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data" stop`

**3- Start:**
Now you should be able to start the postgres from windows service page or by:
`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin>pg_ctl.exe -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data" start`

Answer (score 1):

There is no single easy answer to this question. You must search for the reason of the failure. In my case, was no disk space.

Go to the data Postgre Directory, normally C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data.

Search for the "log" folder. Search for the most recent file and check the error.

In my case, there was a "2024-01-31 07:38:38.286 -03 [6852] PANIC:  could not write to file "pg_wal/xlogtemp.6852": No space left on device" and I easily correct the problem.

The "PANIC" log is the hint. You may search in the web for your specific error.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this error on postgresql-x64-10, with the following logged on the Windows Event viewer (Windows logs -> Application):

- Info: Waiting for server startup...
- Error: postgres: could not access directory ".../PostgreSQL_10_data": No such file or directory
- Error: Run initdb or pg_basebackup to initialize a PostgreSQL data directory.
- Error: Timed out waiting for server startup

The problem in this case turned out to be that the data directory identified in the error was on a portable disk that had gotten disconnected.  Once the disk was connected back to the system, the postgres service started fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change the login account to start the process 
[Local System account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qfjap.png)

Comment: This same exact solution was posted in this question about 6 months prior to yours; I'd suggested doing a quick scan next time to avoid polluting these pages with dups like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64237242/589509

Answer (score 0):

For me, deleting the files did not work.
But restarting the machine after changing the postgres log-on user to 'local system' worked.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when you have 2 versions installed (say 10 and 11).
So, there can be some situations where you want to run 11 but 10 has been started and running already.

So what you want to do is stop 10 and try to start 11.
In windows you can do by, go to run -> then type `services.msc` and find 2 services listed and you can then stop and start.

Answer (score 0):

for me  just remove som file in the  `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data` which 12 is my version  the name of the file is  =>`postmaster.pid` and the `postmaster.conf` then try to run service agine I think it will be work

Comment: Hello, adding on this: make sure there is no PostgreSQL process already running in the background by opening Task Manager and searching for PostgreSQL. If found right click -> End Task.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had issues in the checkpoint log in the transaction record?  (I'd been trying to upgrade from one version to another in Windows, and run into issues)

Could see the error in the most recent log in the data/log directory

> could not locate a valid checkpoint record

If so, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8812934/3038828) showed what wound up working for me, using the pg_resetwal command to reset the WAL.  I don't believe I ever had to use the -f option (though have closed my terminal history, so can't be sure)

For a user called jeopardytempest, for me it would be:

pg_resetwal "C:/users/jeopardytempest/Program Files/PostgreSQL/14/data/"