# Postgres some tables are not working after copying data directory

Tags: postgresql, docker, ruby-on-rails-4, docker-compose

We had an issue with our Hard drive so we copied the data directory into a new hard and we are facing some issues now the issue is I can't read data from three tables for example if I query `Select * from table_name limit 10` it returns me 10 rows but when I try to get a count with `Select count(*) from table name;` it does not return anything and gets stuck. I tried to recover it according to [this fix](https://lxadm.com/Repairing_broken_PostgreSQL_databases_/_tables) but when I try to vaccume the table I get error `ERROR:  uncommitted xmin 60148772 from before xid cutoff 60165118 needs to be frozen`. The data is very important to us if any one can help please let me know what extra details required I have also posted some questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61270018/fatal-bogus-data-in-lock-file-postmaster-pid-after-repairing-disk-and-changin) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61267219/db-contianer-is-not-started-after-moving-data-folder) but now the situation is above at the moment.

Comment: Asking three times doesn't make it better. My advice stands: hire a consultant and pay the price for your negligence. If you are not willing to do that, the data obviously isn't all that important. Be warned, though, that not even an expert can guarantee to rescue your data.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @LaurenzAlbe but my client doesn't like the suggestion he needs the data off-course but wants me to try.

Comment: Then spend a few years working with PostgreSQL, follow the hackers list, read into the source, solve problems, and I'm sure you will be up to the task.