# Get databases from old PostgreSQL folder (win 10)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I need to get databases from the old PostgreSQL folder that was in Program Files (win 10).

I tried changing the data path through the registry (ImagePath
value after "-D" at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\postgresql-x64-12)` from the current to the old PostgreSQL data folder.

I also tried replacing files in the current folder from PostgreSQL with old ones (replaced data for `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data\base and C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data\global)`.

In both cases, an error occurred when trying to start the postgresql-x64-12 service. Error message: `the postgresql-x64-12 service on local computer started and then stopped.` Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.

How can I get databases from old `../Program Files/PostgreSQL` folder?

Comment: Whats is error in postgresql logs?

Comment: @IS Thanks for question about logs! It helped to find a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After replacing the folders `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data\base` and `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data\global` with the old ones and attempts to start the `postgresql-x64-12` service, a log file appeared with the following content:

```
LOG: database system was shut down at ...
LOG: invalid primary checkpoint record
PANIC: could not locate a valid checkpoint record
LOG: startup process (PID 17452) was terminated by exception 0xC0000409
HINT: See C include file "ntstatus.h" for a description of the hexadecimal value.
LOG: aborting startup due to startup process failure
LOG: database system is shut down
```

Because of the message `PANIC: could not locate a valid checkpoint record`, I used pg_resetwal: in PowerShell I opened the folder `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin`, then ran the command `.\pg_resetwal.exe -f -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data`. *In some cases, it is worth using the command without `-f`, also for other versions of Postgres a different command may be needed. More information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8812934/14145682.*

After that, the service also did not start, and the following error was present in the log:

```
FATAL: could not access status of transaction
DETAIL: Could not read from file "pg_multixact/members/0000" at offset 8192: read too few bytes.
```

So, I replaced the files in the `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data\pg_multixact` folder with the old ones.

After these steps, the `postgresql-x64-12` service started without errors and it was possible to restore the old database.

Comment: Lesson learned: don't mess with the DBMS's data files. These are managed by the DBMS, (and the format may depend on Postgres's Major version number) Nothing to see there.