# Docker Postgres 12 'PANIC: could not locate a valid checkpoint record'

Tags: postgresql, docker, caprover

I'm using caprover which uses docker to deploy postgresql 12. Right now my postgresql database is constantly restarting and printing this log everytime:

```
[24] LOG: invalid resource manager ID ...
[24] LOG: invalid primary checkpoint record ...
[24] PANIC: could not locate a valid checkpoint record
```

The problem is that the container dies immediately so I can't do any `docker exec` to try to `pg_dump` or in the worst case scenario `pg_resetwal`.

Any idea why this is happening? How can I possibly `pg_dump` or `pg_resetwal`?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799474/postgresql-error-panic-could-not-locate-a-valid-checkpoint-record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means that you lost WAL information, that is, you lost a file or file contents from at least one of the files in the `pg_wal` subdirectory of the PostgreSQL data directory.

If PostgreSQL crashed, it will recover using the transaction log (WAL). This recovery starts from a checkpoint, whose location is found in the control file (`global/pg_control`). The error message indicates that at the indicated position in the WAL, no checkpoint is found, so PostgreSQL cannot recover.

You have lost some data that is vital to the database. Perhaps a file got deleted, perhaps you have unreliable storage that loses data that an `fsync` request confirmed to be on disk.

Restore from a backup or hire a PostgreSQL expert to salvage data from the remains of your database.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions from this page to reset your wal logs.

https://www.postgresql.r2schools.com/postgresql-panic-could-not-locate-a-valid-checkpoint-record/

Essentially you have to `su` as `postgres` then run the `pg_resetwal` program from the postgres `bin` directory using the data directory as the -f parameter.  Example:

```
$ ./pg_resetwal -f "/var/lib/postgresql/11/main"
```

This should result in:

```
Write-ahead log reset
```

WARNING: You may lose some data or tables.