# Select query doesn't work with specific column condition in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

**Background:**
PostgreSQL service faced some corruption after the server power outage. And I used the pg_resetwal command to fix that issue. *As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799474/postgresql-error-panic-could-not-locate-a-valid-checkpoint-record)*

After the service successfully starts I'm facing this weird issue.

When I query with the id column, it doesn't result anything even the queried data is there and column type matches

```sql
# SELECT id, email FROM users WHERE id=1;
 id | email
----+-------
(0 rows)
```

But if I query with other columns *(in this example, email column)*, it results

```sql
# SELECT id, email FROM users WHERE email='john@gmail.com';
 id |          email
----+--------------------------
 1 | john@gmail.com
(1 row)
```

Any suggestions?

**Postgresql version: 12.7**

Comment: Is this id column numeric or varchar? Can it contain spaces? You could try something like SELECT id, email FROM users WHERE id LIKE '%1%' to check this. If this doesn't help, could you please provide the create table command of this table?

Comment: Did you try to recreate the indexes? `reindex users;`

Comment: @JonasMetzler, the id column is an integer type. So the LIKE operator is not working.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so after you have managed to get your PostgreSQL instance running what you should have done is:

1. Take an immediate backup of all your databases
2. Audit them + check for any damage
3. Drop the existing dbs and restore from the audited backups
4. Identify the mis-configuration in your server that resulted in the data corruption.

I assume you haven't done these things and have a corrupted index.

*Your hardware is lying to PostgreSQL about persisting data to disk*. It isn't safe to trust the existing data - anything that was being updated (not just directly updated by you, but vacuum processess too) is suspect.